# Jenkins Performance plugin result export

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, performance-testing

I am new to the whole devops world and in the process of learning things. 
The context is, I have installed the performance plugin in Jenkins and using jmeter to run my tests. I was able to successfully pull the results into Jenkins and when I hit the performance report I am able to see the graphs with accurate error percentage. Now, I want to export these results (graphs) to an excel sheet for the project team to review the performance trends. How do I do that?

Comment: If you use the "result tab" feature in your jmeter test, it will output a CSV file. Then, you are free to open it with excel and draw some charts.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. I want to export the Jenkins result. I do not have access or visibility to touch the jmeter side. The result I see in Jenkins needs to be exported to excel. Is that possible?

Comment: Upon some research I realized that we use elastic search and kibana in our organization and I can use log stash to pull data from Jenkins. I am trying it out currently. will keep this forum posted with results.